# How to access specific sheet of xlsx file in sqlite3 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I have xlsx or excel file that have multiple sheet and i want check how many sheets are there but using sqlite3 in pandas.

Example-

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
```

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("data.xlsx")
pd.read_sql("select * from sqlite_master where type='table';", conn)
```

```
output
type    name    tbl_name    rootpage    sql
```

But i am not getting number of tables or sheet except the header. Can anybody please solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is like this:
You call `sqlite3.connect` and pass it the name of an Excel file and it creates a new database with that name (if one doesn't already exist) and connects to it.
Then, when you run a SQL query using `pd.read_sql`, it treats the Excel file as if it were an SQLite database and returns the results of the query. And Excel files are not SQL databases!
Instead, to solve your problem you can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_data = pd.ExcelFile('data.xlsx')
print(len(excel_data.sheet_names))
```